# How to remove the last occurrence of "=" symbol from a property file using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties

Here is my content of my Property file and the file name is conf.properties

```
#A_Value='true'
#cache_locators='Server_name:1212'
#ssl_trustore='qa_client_truststore'
#ssl_password='ENC(kYE9WAv/HYjdw='=')'
```

I am trying to convert this property file to json

Code for converting the conf.properties to a json

```
import json
import sys
prop_file = "conf.properties"
import pathlib
file = pathlib.Path(prop_file)
if file.exists ():
    split_properties=[line.split("=") for line in open(prop_file)]
    properties={key: value for key,value in split_properties }
    print(json.dumps(properties))
else:
    print (prop_file+" not found")
```

since there is a multiple `"="` symbol at the last line of `config.properties` , i am getting the following error-

```
properties={key: value for key,value in split_properties }
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I need to remove the multiple occurrences of "=" symbol of the last line of config.properties

from

```
#ssl_password='ENC(kYE9WAv/HYjdw='=')'
```

to

```
#ssl_password='ENC(kYE9WAv/HYjdw)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify how many elements you want while calling the [`.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method:

```
line.split("=", maxsplit=1)
```

This will split once, meaning that you will end up with up to two elements.